# How to create a pool of virtual movie clips that will be used in the future?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am creating a game where enemies are spawned from the library onto the stage. Instead of spawning new enemies, I want to be able to have 20 enemies already made in a "virtual" pool. These enemies will get spawned randomly, and when the player clicks on the enemies, they die and get recycled instead.

This is my loop code to create enemies:

```
 function makeEnemies():void
{
    var chance:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 150);
    if (chance <= level && enemies.length < 4)
    {
        tempEnemy = new Enemy();
        tempEnemy.x = Math.round(Math.random() * 480);
        addChild(tempEnemy);
        tempEnemy.scaleX = 1.5;
        tempEnemy.scaleY = 1.5;
        tempEnemy.cacheAsBitmapMatrix=identityMatrix;
        enemies.push(tempEnemy);

        tempEnemy.speed = enemyBaseSpeed + ((level - 1) * speedLevelInc);
        if (tempEnemy.speed > MAX_SPEED)
        {
            tempEnemy.speed = MAX_SPEED;

        }


    }

}

function moveEnemies():void
{
    var tempEnemy:MovieClip;


    for (var i:int =enemies.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        tempEnemy = enemies[i];
        if (tempEnemy.dead)
        {
            score++;
            score++;
            roachLevel.score_txt.text = String(score);
            enemies.splice(i,1);

        }
        else
        {

            tempEnemy.rotation += (Math.round(Math.random()*.4));
            tempEnemy.y +=  (Math.cos((Math.PI/180)*tempEnemy.rotation))*tempEnemy.speed;
            if (tempEnemy.x < 10)
            {
                tempEnemy.x = 11;
            }
            if (tempEnemy.x > stage.stageWidth - offset)
            {
                tempEnemy.x = stage.stageWidth - offset;
            }
            if (tempEnemy.y > stage.stageHeight)
            {
                removeEnemy(i);

                lives--;
                roachLevel.lives_txt.text = String(lives);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't want to use classes. Just the code inside the layer.

Comment: Have you tried implementing it? From the sounds of it you already know exactly how it works. It's as simple as one single array.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to 'recycle' these enemies, what you could do is create an array, for argument sake, let's call this array `enemyPool`, and whenever a player kills an enemy, get the reference to it, make the `removeChild` call to remove it from the stage, and then using the reference again, store the enemy object into the `enemyPool` array.

Whenever you need another enemy to be put back on to the screen, simply pop one off the `enemyPool` array, perform whatever initializing on that object again before you make your `addChild` call to show them on the screen again.

Comment: Could you tell me how the putting the enemies on stage code would be like? And the recycling code as well?